# How to take backup from mysql database which is contains bulk amount of records?

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have 10k records in my mysql database, when i try to take backup from sqlyog or with command  like below

```
mysqldump -u <user-name> -p<password> <database-name> > <fine-name>
```

output file not in proper formation that seems like below, and if I try to import this file in another database its giving error. Its works fine when i have small amount of records.

```
º=Ã\0Ã¨Ã·\0\0\0aÂÂÂ¼\0\'Å“X\0`Å“D\0Ã¶d\0`Ã¬DÅ½\'VÃ„ii   \0Ã†\'\0OÅ“(\0`|qâ€š\0â‚¬Ã±Ã…â€°\0Ã†\0\0\0\0\0â€”Ã \0ÂÃ³bKÂ´Â´ÃÃ€Ã¸\Zâ‚¬Ã±  4,\0Ã£hP\0Ã†+$  â€¹Â±ÃƒÃ‘Æ’r<\0Å’k\Z\n\0Ã—\0\0!\0\0\0\0@`{>Ë†ÃŸ{Ã·}Â¥Ã½Ã•Å½z1\'Â¶SdÃœâ‚¬\0 Ã£>\Z,ÃŽÂ­{@Ã‹Ââ‚¬(Ã°â€¹Â­Ã»â€¢Ã¶Ã’Ãq`tLÃ¬Ãª7>%>â€¢_\"â€™\0ÂÃ‘Ã¼Â xâ€¡2Ã¶ÃŸ\ZoÃŸÂ¾Ã½\rÃ±Ã©Ã¿Ã–hÃ«â€”Â¬Â¯tÂ¤%â‚¬\0\0Hw^xÂ«RiÂ\\ÂºÃªËœ(Ã¸Ã‘Ã˜Ã‘Ã­Ã¸rqÂµHÃ‹f0Ã™Â¹ii ;\'Ã*Ã­Ã¸Ã¤â€cÂ²Ëœâ‚¬Å’Ã‡?Ã·lÃMÃ±gUÃ»Drâ€š \0   @\0HÃž>Ã²â€°Ã’NÃ†Ã£Ã¢ÃŒÃ›^7Â·Ã€Ã·\nÃ…ÃÂ±qqU}â€œHâ€¹\0Ã©Ã‰Ã‚Â¼Â¢%FZÃ‚ÃŠÂ7Ã¯UÃšâ€˜Ã±  Ã‘Ã‰â€žÂ¦Â¹Â­.Ã¼Â¸YÃ¼Ã†ÃªÂ\"Ã™â€˜6A*Ã®BÅ’YÃ•Ã±iÃ·\rqfË†%lnÂ¯\rÂ·&&Ã…Ãg.Å Ã¦Ã­sÃ¨\Z:Ã£Ã²â€ž\0Â\0$O\0Ã‚Ã‡Ã³Ã«6)mÃƒÃ….Ã‘LbÅ¾-ÃŒâ€™\rÂ¼Ã™Ã‚1Ã‘Ã—NÃ…oâ€¹Â­Ã—Ã»Ã„â€”KvË†Å“Â©CÃ½Ë†UÂ§ÃŽ+Â­yÃ™â€˜(Ã„Â¼Ã lÂ¡8WÅ¡Â¿Ã¯Ã¬_Â«>Ã HÂ¾Ã°â‚¬ \0xÃ¡7Âµ)Ã­Ã¨Ã„Â¤8W0Ãx6Å¸   &ÃºÃœÃ«CÂ·Ã—<.râ‚¬\0{<]PÃ°Â â€“â€“â‚¬0Ã²Ãâ€¢{â€Â¶{`XÅ“+Â´Ã¦\nÂ·d^â€šÃ¸Â¹Â¾câ€œâ€œbÃ¹Ã±3Ã¢Å¸Â¼Y&â€™7\0Ã°Â¼Ã´Ã®Ã»ÃŠÃ˜Ã²Ã™\rqÂ®Â«9ÃÃ±Ã¼Nâ€“Å¾+<\'Â¦Ã¢Â¢)Â»ÃµÃ½Â¢m\"g\0@HÅ¾Ã¬Â¼
```

Can you help me any one to take backup of my database.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Following command will help to make database dump .

```
     mysqldump -u<username> -p<password> <databasename> > targetfilename.sql
```

Comment: I want in windows only

Comment: you can use it in windows also.

Answer (score 0):

Its good to take backup for physical files if its very huge database.
Perform the below activity  for the same.
Search for below files (You should do it while the server is not running.)

```
XYZ.frm
XYZ.MYD
XYZ.MYI
```

where XYZ is name of your database.
Copy it somewhere in other location and you are done.

You can also use command  `mysqlhotcopy` to achieve the same
Its very fast and reliable approach.

For information go to link [mysqlhotcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html)

```
shell> mysqlhotcopy db_name [/path/to/new_directory]
shell> mysqlhotcopy db_name_1 ... db_name_n /path/to/new_directory
```

To restore the same you can mount the Database again.

A MySQL table is the combination of three files:

The FRM file is the table definition.
The MYD file is the where the actual data is stored.
The MYI file is the where the indexes created on the table are stored.
You should be able to restore by copying them in your database folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another viable option is exporting the table to one file using the phpMyAdmin export feature. I find this a lot simpler than manually finding the files through the terminal. Just log in to [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.co) and hit export. It's as simple as that.

Comment: As you said I tried to login in http://www.phpmyadmin.co/index.php but its giving error like, "1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server". What to do now. I given username and password what mysql have and server: localhost.